# FFTW advance interface: fftw_plan_many_r2r() does not work

Tags: c++, fftw, dct

I'm trying to implement 1D discrete cosine transform (type-I or any) for x and z direction when an input is an 1D array of size nx * nz flattened from the 2D nx by nz matrix. To do this, i'm using the fftw_plan_many_r2r() function in the intel MKL library. however, fftw_handle is set to NULL after set fftw_plan and segmentation fault occurs when execute the fft plans.
Here is my code. It seems okay for me, however, does not work.. Expecting your help!

by the way, i'm using other fftw advanced interfaces such as fftw_plan_many_dft, fftw_plan_many_dft_r2c and fftw_plan_many_dft_c2r routines very well.. So it feels more embarrassing.. When making the program, I refered the page (http://www.fftw.org/pruned.html)

---

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
#include <fftw/fftw3_mkl.h>

void main()
{
    // dimensions
    int nx = 4;
    int nz = 5;

    // plans
    fftw_plan plan_forward_x;
    fftw_plan plan_forward_z;

    // matrices
    std::vector<double> M_in = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f,  // ->> z-dir
                                 1.0f, 3.0f, 5.0f, 7.0f, 9.0f,
                                 6.0f, 2.0f, 7.0f, 3.0f, 1.0f,
                                 6.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 3.0f, 1.0f };
    std::vector<double> M_out(nx*nz);
    std::vector<double> Mkx(nx*nz);
    std::vector<double> Mkz(nx*nz);

    // set batched 1D DCT-1 plans for x-directional transformation
    {
         int rank = 1;
         int batch = nz;
         int inembed_x[] = { 0 };
         int idist = 1;
         int istride = nz;
         int onembed_x[] = { 0 };
         int odist = 1;
         int ostride = nz;
         fftw_r2r_kind kind = FFTW_REDFT00; // DCT-1
         plan_forward_x = fftw_plan_many_r2r(rank, &nx, batch, 
                                      M_in.data(), inembed_x, istride, idist, 
                                      Mkx.data(), onembed_x, ostride, odist, 
                                      &kind, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    }
    // set batched 1D DCT-1 plans for z-directional transformation
    {
         int rank = 1;
         int batch = nx;
         int idist = nz;
         int odist = nz;
         int inembed_z[] = { 0 };
         int onembed_z[] = { 0 };
         int istride = 1;
         int ostride = 1;
         fftw_r2r_kind kind = FFTW_REDFT00; // DCT-1
         plan_forward_z = fftw_plan_many_r2r(rank, &nz, batch, 
                                      M_in.data(), inembed_z, istride, idist, 
                                      Mkz.data(), onembed_z, ostride, odist, 
                                      &kind, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    }

    // execution
    fftw_execute(plan_forward_x);
    fftw_execute(plan_forward_z);

    // free fftw routines
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan_forward_x);
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan_forward_z);
    fftw_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you have a pointer, you should *always* check for it being a null pointer. As for why, have you tried to read the documentation about possible ways to get errors or error codes?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow ! See http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Advanced-Complex-DFTs.html#Advanced-Complex-DFTs About the inembed and onembed arguments: n should be elementwise less than or equal to {i,o}nembed. Since nx and nz are larger than 0, the plan creation likely fails and returns NULL. You can also turn on the verbose mode for debug. See https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-using-fftw3-wrappers : `fftw3_mkl.verbose = 0;`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @francis ! Even when I change  {i,o}nembed into {nx} and {nz} for x- and z- directional DCT plans, respectively, it does not work. Don't you have a very simple code using the fftw_plan_many_r2r routine? Anyway, the code works when I link the original FFTW3 version from [http://www.fftw.org](http://www.fftw.org/)... But I want to use MKL version to reduce CPU time..

Comment: Oh, Multidimensional r2r transforms is not supported by MKL... Do Intel have any plan to include the function in the future?